# Mysql query for only current user

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, filtering

I've started using the wpdatatables plugin,
In the backend it has a place to enter a MySql query for it to create a table.

I have:

```
SELECT id, currentuserid, text, date_created
FROM  `1items` 
WHERE currentuserid = %d
ORDER BY  `1items`.`currentuserid`
```

Which lists all the tables I need to pull from the database, however, I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically filter in MySql for only the current user's ID.

In the second column "currentuserid" it pulls all the user's ID's and inputs them into the table.

Example: If I am logged in as user ID 4 - I would like the query to filter out the other users -- as of now, The above query returns tables from all user ID's.

When searching wordpress stackexchange, I located this: [PHP MySQL query - return results for current user only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673422/php-mysql-query-return-results-for-current-user-only) 
Which doesn't work, or I am not using it right with wpdatatables.

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell based on your naming, but it looks like the query you listed should already do what you want (filtering `WHERE currentuserid = %d`). Presumably the `%d` is the current user ID, right? Your `ORDER BY` doesn't do anything though.

Comment: I got WHERE currentuserid = %d from another stackexchange question- it actually returns no results (unless I put a user's ID.) So I am hoping there is something like %d that would dynamically return the logged in user's results.  thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

%d is a placeholder, it has no intrinsic value of its own. It's used in a prepare statement to help protect against SQL injection attacks

So you need to do something like this:

```
$currentUser    = get_current_user_id();

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        SELECT id, currentuserid, text, date_created
        FROM  `1items` 
        WHERE currentuserid = %d
    ", 
        $currentUser
) );
```

As Brendan Long points out the order by doesn't do anything when return a single user's results.